# Can I store Gstreamer output to buffer using opencv . If I add appsink in pipline

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, opencv3.0, encoder, gstreamer-1.0

Hello I am very new to gstreamer. As of now I am encoding frames using gstreamer pipeline in opencv in c++. But now I do not want dump each frame. I want to encode all frames and store it in a large buffer and whenever I want I will dump that buffer. so how can I do appsink in gstreamer opencv.

Below my code snippet where i am encoding each frame and dumping also

```
cv::VideoWriter out("appsrc !  videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! v4l2h264enc ! avimux ! filesink location=hellotest.avi",cv::CAP_GSTREAMER,0,30,cv::Size(1280,720),true);
out.write(Frame);
```

But I want appsink to store all encoded data into buffer I do not want to dump it or write it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

First of all you cannot write and read at the sametime with `VideoWriter`. What you can do is you can create two pipelines that communicate with each other using [ipcpipeline](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/ipcpipeline/index.html?gi-language=c) elements.

For example

```
cv::VideoWriter out("appsrc !  videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! v4l2h264enc ! ipcpipelinesink",...);
cv::VideoCapture cap("ipcpipelinesrc ! ... ! appsink")
```

But this won't provide you with many alternatives because the data formats supported with `VideoCapture` is very limited, if you check the [souce code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp).

```
// we support 11 types of data:
//     video/x-raw, format=BGR   -> 8bit, 3 channels
//     video/x-raw, format=GRAY8 -> 8bit, 1 channel
//     video/x-raw, format=UYVY  -> 8bit, 2 channel
//     video/x-raw, format=YUY2  -> 8bit, 2 channel
//     video/x-raw, format=YVYU  -> 8bit, 2 channel
//     video/x-raw, format=NV12  -> 8bit, 1 channel (height is 1.5x larger than true height)
//     video/x-raw, format=NV21  -> 8bit, 1 channel (height is 1.5x larger than true height)
//     video/x-raw, format=YV12  -> 8bit, 1 channel (height is 1.5x larger than true height)
//     video/x-raw, format=I420  -> 8bit, 1 channel (height is 1.5x larger than true height)
//     video/x-bayer             -> 8bit, 1 channel
//     image/jpeg                -> 8bit, mjpeg: buffer_size x 1 x 1
// bayer data is never decoded, the user is responsible for that
// everything is 8 bit, so we just test the caps for bit depth
```

Comment: getting this error GStreamer warning: error opening writer pipeline: could not link jpegenc0 to ipcpipelinesrc0